# Can I get this theme in Unity?

Tags: unity, kubuntu, themes

I recently saw this photo online and got attracted towards it. I know that this a kubuntu desktop and i dont want the upside down dock as shown in this pic but I just want the indicator or whatever you say to that thing which at the right side of this pic indicating weather and all those stuff. is that an extra add on and can I get this for unity.

[image]

Comment: Do you have anything for us to go on as to which theme you are talking about?

Comment: sorry i will add it

Comment: i have added it now and thanks for that comment

Comment: The indicator is a program called 'conky' which is highly configurable.  I don't use it myself, so I can't give you any advise, but there's lots of documentation for it on the web, and apparently many pre-configured themes for it.

Comment: why was this downvoted

Answer (score 1):

Neither the desktop is KDE but LXDE, and the column information in the right side is called conky.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpConky

Comment: OMG it is really very complicated to set this thing up

Comment: This is a couple of really easy setups and tools: http://helmuthdu.deviantart.com/art/CONKY-COLORS-244793180 http://zagortenay333.deviantart.com/art/Conky-Harmattan-426662366 http://www.webupd8.org/2013/07/conky-manager-gui-for-managing-conky.html